# <OCHamcrestIOS/OCHamcrestIOS.h> not found after pod install

Tags: ios, cocoapods, header-files, ochamcrest

In my podspec for my project, I have :

```
s.dependency 'OCHamcrest'
```

I keep on getting the above error. In `Pods/Headers`, I noticed the following path :

```
Pods/Headers/Public/OCHamcrest/OCHamcrest.h
```

Also, there is nothing in my `HEADER SEARCH PATHS`. Has anyone run into this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For CocoaPod-installed OCHamcrest, use the following import:

```
#import <OCHamcrest/OCHamcrest.h>
```

(This is noted in the README, under "CocoaPods".)